# ZEND Internal Server Error (WAMP)

Tags: php, zend-framework

I already install zend framework and i used wamp server to let it works then in httpconfig i inserted

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1
```

```
DocumentRoot "C:\Workspace\zendy\public"
ServerName zendy

    <Directory "C:\Workspace\zendy\public">
         Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit Indexes

            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

after restarting wamp server ... the below message appears

> Internal Server Error

i know the error in virtualhost. however, i couldn't solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable rewrite module directly by clicking wamp tray icon and going into Apache settings. Like example below.

[image]

If you still find some problems you may need to add zendy server name to your system C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 zendy
```

Also you must uncomment vhosts in Apache httpd.conf:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

just look into Apache Error Log, you should see what exactly caused Internal Server Error there

Comment: C:/workspace/zendy/public/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: you got it! To enable the module edit apache’s httpd.conf file and make sure this line is there uncommented: LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so